# PHPUnit code coverage report in Clover XML format contains interfaces

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, clover

I use the `@codeCoverageIgnore` annotation in order to ignore interfaces in code coverage reports. Some time ago I have used code coverage report in HTML format and I have not found any issues while I have used this format. I am going to use code coverage report in Clover XML format. I generated the first report in this format and I found that there are interfaces. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried ignoring from phpunit.xml?

Comment: What do you mean? Specifying the suffix `Interface`? I excluded the directories with tests and vendors.

Comment: Yes, there are some examples in the documentation http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html

Comment: Thank for the advice. I am not sure that this is the best solution. However, this will work. I also found the similar issue on GitHub https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/497.